# php's framework codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

i have a some problem in codeigniter session, when a page load..session value unset during page loading ..means some session variable unset( means null)...session variable before page load..

```
Array ( [session_id] => 2de4cec5bf6cdf3ccc5b02844a4b572a 
        [ip_address] => 127.0.0.1 
        [user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:5.0) Gecko/2010010 
        [last_activity] => 1320479523 
        [logoff_city] => Agra 
        [user_deal_point] => 460 
        [userid] => 2 
        [email] => test@dummyid.com 
        [asfsadf] => 
        [userId] => 
        [city_name] => Agra 
        [city_id] => 1 
        [deal_id] => KGrNM03 
        [amount] => 449 
        [total_amount] => 449 
        [UserName] => 
        [UserEmail] => 
        [Mobile] => )
```

After page loading show session variable

```
Array ( [session_id] => 2de4cec5bf6cdf3ccc5b02844a4b572a 
        [ip_address] => 127.0.0.1 
        [user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:5.0) Gecko/2010010 
        [last_activity] => 1320479523 
        [logoff_city] => Agra 
        [user_deal_point] => 
        [userid] => 2 
        [email] => test@dummyid 
        [asfsadf] => 
        [userId] => 
        [city_name] => Agra 
        [city_id] => 1 
        [UserName] => 
        [UserEmail] => 
        [Mobile] => )
```

Comment: Please spend some time formatting your question - use the `{}` button for code blocks for example, see the help in the editor. As it is, your post is unreadable, and your "question" isn't a question (you're not asking anyting), and I don't see how it could be answered - you provide no information whatsoever about the context in which this appears.

Comment: Are you using the session class? It has a userdata set of functions for setting ad retrieving data.

Answer (score 2):

Have you upgraded from a 1.7 version of CodeIgniter to a 2.0 version? And are you storing sessions in a database table? And are you using IE? If so, I had this same problem. It was fixed when I edited the session table, user_agent field to a varchar(255). It's an issue with IE.

Comment: I see your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7904439/loosing-a-session-variable-between-one-page-with-codeigniter-session-library, and I had this strange problem too. I never experienced this before... Already change to database session, not working.

Answer (score 0):

See this for the answer for this problem : [Losing a session variable between one page with codeigniter session library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7904439/loosing-a-session-variable-between-one-page-with-codeigniter-session-library/9137793#9137793)

To sum up, you had missing resource(s) file.

Good luck!