# Codeigniter - Session variables mysteriously disappearing

Tags: codeigniter, session, codeigniter-2

I am using Codeigniter 2.1.0 and CI_session for session handling.

I assume that this

1. Page A sets some variables in the session using $this->session->set_userdata().
2. Page A redirects to Page B
3. Page B is expected to retain the session variables that were set in Page A.

However this is what happens to me

1. Page A sets some variables in the session using $this->session->set_userdata().
2. Page A redirects to Page B
3. Page B does not retain the session variables that were set in Page A.

I have code in Page A to save and record the contents of $this->session->userdata in a log before redirection to Page B. The log shows that the values that are set in session exist.

However, using var_dump() on $this->session->userdata on Page B shows that those values don't exists.

I don't really know how this could be. I have double checked that I am not unsetting the values in Page B. It's like CI_Session is somehow unsetting them behind the scenes.

Any ideas?

EDIT: Yes, I am using the database to save session data. The field type is TEXT.

Comment: are you saving your session data to database...if not try saving the sessions data to database... `$config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE;`.. and check...

Comment: is it happening in all browsers?

Comment: Is it all the session data? or just some of it? If your session data is exceeding the size of the cookie restrictions, not all of it will be passed across. Try saving them to the database if your not already.

Comment: @bipen I have updated my question to answer your question

Comment: @ShayanHusaini Yes. It is happening to all browsers.

Comment: I don't think anyone will be able to help you any further without seeing some code.

Comment: @Jeemusu Not all session data. Just some of it.

Comment: When you load page A, does your database session data table experience any changes?

Comment: @Vlakarados When it works properly yes. When the variables that were supposed to be set in session cannot be accessed in Page B, there were no changes.

Comment: @arvinsim Without seeing your code, the only advice I can give you is to check your HTML, CSS, JS, make sure everything validates, isn't broken, and that you have no missing resources on your page, as this has from time to time been known to cause problems with the Codeigniter sessions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7775611/codeigniter-setting-session-variable-with-a-variable-not-working | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7904439/loosing-a-session-variable-between-one-page-with-codeigniter-session-library

Comment: Is page A and page B on the same domain?

Comment: @repox Page A and Page B are in the same domain.

Comment: Check if your cookie settings are correct. CI creates a cookie for you with your session ID. Have a look at the cookie with tools like firebug or chrome developer tool and check if the session ID doesn't change in the cookie between  the page refresh

Comment: are you redirecting the page using js after you make an ajax call?

Comment: show yuor code, maybe your are mistaking somenthing

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand from networks, the cookies and sessions are stored in client machine and not server. So HTTP basically adds cookies and sessions to your request headers and sends the request.

But in this case you are setting the sessions and then redirecting from the same page in server. Normal PHP might handle this differently but codeIgniter does not use native PHP sessions. (Refer http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html)

This is my guess. But it would be helpful if I take a look at your code.